# Android Data Binding with parameter passing to method

Tags: android, android-databinding

> First, this question is not a case of 'onClick' event parameter passing.

I have DateUtil class with one method as below :

```
public static String formatDate(long date) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        c.setTimeInMillis(date);
        return dateFormat.format(c.getTimeInMillis());
    }
```

My model CommentEntity has following attributes :

```
 private int id;
 private int productId;
 private String text;
 private Date postedAt;
```

Now in one of layout I'm displaying the Comments.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="comment"
                  type="com.example.entity.CommentEntity"/>
        <variable
        name="dateUtil"
        type="com.example.util.DateUtil"/>

    </data>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/item_comment_text"

                //This line gives error for data binding
                android:text="@{dateUtil.formatDate(comment.postedAt.time)}"/>
</layout>
```

The error I'm getting is :

> cannot find method
>   formatDate(com.example.util.DateUtil) in class
>   long

Now for the same if I modify formatDate() method as it will take current time by default, hence removing the parameter passing in data binding, it will work perfectly.

So am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

*Please provide solution for problem to pass the parameter to method in data binding.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below approach:

1. Don't take your **`DateUtil`** class object direct from data binding in **xml**

Make one **BindingAdapter** method in your **`CommentEntity` model** class like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setPaddingLeft(TextView view, long date) {
    view.setText(DateUtil.formatDate(long));
}
```

Then use like below for xml:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_comment_text"
            android:text="@{comment.postedAt.time}"/>
```

---

**Explanation :**

When you wanted to apply some custom logic for your **view** based on **data model**, you need to use **[BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)** to do that job. So, you can provide some custom tag or use any default `android:` tag on which you need to set logic.

I denied you using `DateUtil` for binding adapter because, you might be using it's methods to somewhere else too. So suggested to make new method in your model instead for that logic, so that core logic remains untouched. *(You can use your `DateUtils` for this logic though, you just need to make it as **BindingAdapter**).*

Comment: Awesome !!! Thanks for that great explanation. But why can't we pass arguments in data binding?

Answer (score 0):

since you want to use a static method in `DateUtil` you should import it:

```
<data>
    <variable ... />
    <import type="foo.bar.DateUtil"/>
</data>
```

and in `TextView`:

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/item_comment_text"
               //use DateUtil directly-
                android:text="@{DateUtil.formatDate(comment.postedAt.time)}"/>
```

your error was trying to use it as a `variable` - this tells databinding to expect this class instance to be bound somewhere in your UI class (Fargment/Activity)